# Python accessing data.europa.eu online datasets for road traffic accidents

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, download

I was wondering how I could access the datasets of the different years from data.europa online (https://data.europa.eu/data/datasets/road-traffic-accidents/), and load them in a pandas dataframe. I tried with the help of the API documentation but didn't get far. Help is appreciated!

Edit: I would like to know how to access it online, I know it can be downloaded manually, but accessing the data with a web request is something I was interested in learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can download these files manually, which presumably results in a `.csv` file. Then, you can use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/downloaded/csv/file.csv")
```

This should the .csv file into a pandas DataFrame for you.